# EF migrations with model in different project

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, migration

Everytime I run the command `Add-Migration -Context ApplicationDbContext` in the package manager console the migration seems to be trying to create a table which already exists in another DbContext.

I have the following project structure:

[image]

The table I would like to be created is the `CheckoutToken` model:

```
public class CheckoutToken
{
   [Key]
   public string Token { get; set; }

   public string UserId { get; set; }

   public int LicenseId { get; set; }

   public DateTime Created { get; set; }

   public DateTime Expires { get; set; }

   public License License { get; set; }

   public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

The `ApplicationUser` model is a table which exists, this is the model:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
   public bool SmsTwoFactorEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

When I run the Add-Migration command I get a migration which looks like it's trying to create a table called "ApplicationUser" in the `Up()` method like so:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
  name: "ApplicationUser",
  columns: table => new
  {
     Id = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
     UserName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
     NormalizedUserName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
     Email = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
     NormalizedEmail = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
     EmailConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
     PasswordHash = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
     SecurityStamp = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
     ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
     PhoneNumber = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
     PhoneNumberConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
     TwoFactorEnabled = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
     LockoutEnd = table.Column<DateTimeOffset>(nullable: true),
     LockoutEnabled = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
     AccessFailedCount = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
     SmsTwoFactorEnabled = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false)
   },
   constraints: table =>
   {
      table.PrimaryKey("PK_ApplicationUser", x => x.Id);
   });
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, I thought EF would know the ApplicationUser is the `AspNetUsers` table and that by linking have a foreign key relationship from `CheckoutToken` it would know that it's a dependency and not a new table.

I don't have the ApplicationUser table in my DbContext as DbSet too:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<LicenseType> LicenseTypes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<License> Licenses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CheckoutToken> CheckoutTokens { get; set; }

        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
       : base(options)
        { }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.SeedEnumValues<LicenseType, LicenseTypeEnum>(e => e);
        }
    }
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I've been confused for days now

Answer (score 0):

Since, there have two DB context in your application (IdentityDbContext and ApplicationDbContext), perhaps they are using different Database to store the table. You could check the ConfigureServices method in the Startup.cs or IdentityHostingStartup.cs file, make sure they are using the same connection string.

```
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("IndentityDbContextConnection"))); 

            services.AddDbContext<IndentityDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                 Configuration.GetConnectionString("IndentityDbContextConnection")));
```

Besides, for the ApplicationDbContext, try to modify the code as below:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
```

Then, enable migration to check the result.

Edit:

If still not working, try to remove the unnecessary statement in the Up() and Down() methods.

Besides, if you meet the new property not add to the AspNetUsers issue, try to add the following code in the Up()/Down() method, for example (using the following code to add Address columns in the AspNetUsers table, after that, update the database using migration):

```
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
         name: "Address",
         table: "AspNetUsers",
         nullable: false,
         defaultValue: 0);
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
         name: "Address",
         table: "AspNetUsers");
    }
```

Comment: Although I've derived from the .NET Core `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` when I create a migration it looks like it's trying to create all of the identity tables i.e AspNetUsers, AspNetRoles etc.. I've also checked to ensure the `Startup.cs` file and checked if both context's are using the same connection string and this is true.

Comment: @KTOV, Try to remove the unnecessary statement in the Up() and Down() methods.